# Python: how to find the best params for the effective execution

Tags: python, time, timeit

I have a func which depends on number of processes and batch size

```
def test(data, n_process=1, batch_size=1):
    data = helper_func(data, n_process=n_process, batch_size=batch_size)

    ... do smth    

    return data
```

I want to try different value of `n_process` and `batch_size`.
It's possible to do that using information about the time

```
from time import time
start = time()
```

But is it possible to do that specifying lists of possible values for each argument to find the best time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some hyperparameter optimization framework like [`optuna`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Instead of returning the data, return a metric or loss and optimize towards it.